# In the Azure Table Storage SDK, what is the purpose of GenerateFilterCondition?

Tags: linq, azure, azure-table-storage

In the [Azure Table Storage SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet), there are numerous examples of constructing LINQ queries over Tables using code in the form:

```
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"));
```

I understand that `GenerateFilterCondition` creates a predicate to pass to `Where` - which works in the same way a (for example) `Func<CustomerEntity, bool>` would, but I can't find anything that explains why it's required as opposed to writing:

```
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(c => c.PartitionKey == "Smith");
```

What does this helper method do for you that writing a straightforward lambda expression like 'normal' LINQ does not?

Answer (score 0):

May be it caused by strong assumption, that you will almost always query data by specifing `RowKey` and `PartitionKey` - it is fast(due to inner azure storage tables architecture) and predictable, but if you want to build more complex search condition, you should use `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` builder instead of standart *Entity Framework* `.Where` like predicate, i.e. `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Also I think  `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` will not offer you something special except of goal opportunities.

If you want to use comfortable predicate syntax, you can use [Azure.TableStorage.API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.TableStorage.API/) library, which allow you to write queries like this:

```
var api = new AzureTableStorageAPI();
var date = new DateTime(1990, 1, 10);
var persons = api.GetEntities<Person>(x => x.BirthDay > date && x.PartitionKey == "Man" && (x.Age > 30 || x.Name == "Mike"));
```